# Are there sects that explicitly deny caste/varna/jati and do not practice it in real life?

Tags: caste-system

There may be sects that deny caste in their sectarian works but practice it in their real life.  Are there any sects who actual do not practice the caste system?

Comment: Relevant: https://scroll.in/article/802759/beyond-hinduism-is-caste-a-religious-or-a-regional-problem

Comment: Lingayat people...

Comment: maybe thats why they want to split from Hinduism @rakesh joshi